# Clothes tearing during animation

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm importing two OBJs from Poser.  One is the body and the other is a jacket.  I apply the cloth modifier to the jacket and collision to the body.  When I animate it the jacket tears apart.  Any guesses as to what is going on?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

FYI : I didn't realize I didn't weld the seams in export.  I thought I did.  It was breaking on the seams.